# Custom Observable with setInterval with different polling duration

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am new to RxJS / Angular stuff and I am trying to implement a custom Observable for a polling kind of scenario.

Scenario:
From a button component in Angular typescript, I want to kickoff polling mechanism on a button click, get some data from an API, return the data back to the button component and based on the response I either want to call next(), complete() or error() on the button component where I actually do `.subscribe()`.

**Backend service API method** myApi.service.ts

```
getSomeValue(input: string[]): Observable<MyModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<MyModel[]>(
      `${<some-base-url>}/my-endpoint`,
    );
  }
```

**Polling service** polling.service.ts

```
startPolling(delayInMiliseconds: number): Observable<MyModel> {
    this.myObservable$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this.myInterval= setInterval(() => {
        this.myApi.getSomeValue().subscribe(data => {

          if (<some-condition>) {
            observer.next(status);
          }
          else if (<some-condition>) {
            observer.error();
          }
          else if (<some-condition>) {
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      }, delayInMiliseconds);
    })
    return this.myObservable$;
  }
```

**button.component.ts**

```
private onButtonClick(): void {
   pollingService.startPolling(originalDelayInMiliseconds)
      .subscribe( 
        (data) => {
          if(data === something) {
            
            console.log("This is the next poll / call to backend API");
            let updatedDelayInMilisecondsInMiliseconds = recalculateDelayInMiliseconds();
            // Do something so that polling continue with new updatedDelayInMilisecondsInMiliseconds 
and I reset the interval defined in pollingService.
          }
        },
        () => {
           console.log("I errored out");
           polllingService.stopInterval(); // This is working
        },
        () => {
          console.log("I am completed");
          polllingService.stopInterval(); // This is working

        }
    )
}
```

**Problem**

1. When the backend service is called first time using observable, it calls with delay of `originalDelayInMiliseconds`, this is correct and expected.
2. Now I want to call the same API via observable with the `updatedDelayInMilisecondsInMiliseconds`.
   How can I call with the updated time, it gets called with the originalDelayInMiliseconds everytime
3. I will stop based on some condition but that is not the issue.

**Things tried**

1. clearInterval in the next Handler in button component, so that it can take new miliseconds.
2. calling the same pollingService.startPolling
3. unsubscribe.
4. repeatWhen in observable

**Please help** Any other suggestions??

Comment: the tricky part that you are missing @Drenai missing is the ability to change interval lengths

Answer (score 0):

```
class PollingService {
  private pollingSubject = new Subject();

  startPolling(initialDelay: number) {
    this.pollAgain(initialDelay);
    return this.pollingSubject.asObservable();
  }

  pollAgain(delay: number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.pollingSubject.next();
    }, delay);
  }
  stopPolling() {
    this.pollingSubject.complete();
  }
}
```

used like

```
 pollingService.startPolling(originalDelayInMiliseconds)
      .subscribe( 
        (data) => {
          if(data === something) {
            
            console.log("This is the next poll / call to backend API");
            let updatedDelayInMilisecondsInMiliseconds = recalculateDelayInMiliseconds();
            pollingService.pollAgain(updatedDelayInMilisecondsInMiliseconds)
```